# Why do my blocking Futures not run on single core?

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

When I run the following (simplified) code on a low powered server with only 1 core:

```
implicit val context: ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global

Future(blocking {
  while (true) {
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("thread 1")
  }
})

while (true) {
  java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
  println("main")
}
```

Only "main" shows up in the logs. If I increase the server to have more cores, then it works.  What am I doing wrong? How to make Scala/Java run every thread even when there are limited cores?

My understanding is that the runtime should use some logic to execute one thread for a bit, then switch to the other thread.

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
```

After a bit of playing around, I found that if I use `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30))` for my EC it works.  So something about the way I understand the global EC & blocking must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to replicate this problem. Even on a single core there should be at least one thread available when using `ExecutionContext.global` because the default calculations is

```
numThreads = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors * 1
```

and so

```
Future(blocking {
  while (true) {
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("thread 1")
  }
})
```

should execute in that thread whilst

```
while (true) {
  java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
  println("main")
}
```

should execute in the main thread.

Note even with just a single thread available, if you consistently used `blocking {}` then new threads would still be spawned up to `maxExtraThreads`

```
scala.concurrent.context.maxExtraThreads = defaults to "256"
```

Hence the problem likely lies somewhere else.